# C++20 subtract a day from year_month_day

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I see that there is an operator -= on year_month_day, but this:

```
auto tp = zoned_time{current_zone(), now}.get_local_time();
auto dp = floor<days>(tp);
year_month_day ymd(dp);
ymd -= 1d; // this is not possible ?!
```

the overloaded operator seems implemented only for months and years.
Why it is so?

Comment: just do the arithmetic on `tp` before converting to `year_month_day`

Comment: I'm not sure why it was designed this way, but from cppreference: *An implicit conversion to and from std::chrono::sys_days allows std::chrono::days-oriented arithmetic to be performed efficiently.*

Comment: @NathanOliver this link from the duplicate explains it https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/FAQ#day_arithmetic

Comment: @AlanBirtles just to say yesterday i tried to push a date forward adding 1 month to now like you're proposing and it changed the time too.... I'm not sure what kind of weird behaviours can come out doing that...

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks, the link seems full of explanations, I wish those were already copied on the usual cpp documentations online!

Comment: cppreference is an editable wiki, if you think the documentation is lacking something then edit it in